# Customising the php error messages in WAMP - Is it possible?

Tags: wamp

The error messages that PHP throws up in WAMP are really ugly and very difficult to read when viewed through the dev console (when debugging xml requests).

[image: WAMP PHP Error Message]

Is there an easy way to improve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That format of error message is generated by XDEBUG.

XDEBUG is an additional feature that comes with WAMPServer and is a very useful debugging tool but it can be disabled if you really want to.

Edit the `php.ini` file ( using the wampmanager menus ) and near the bottom of the file you will find a line something like this ( your version numbers may be different )

```
; XDEBUG Extension

zend_extension = "d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll"
```

Comment out the zend_extension line like this with a semi colon in column 1

```
;zend_extension = "d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.28/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.3-vc9.dll"
```

Only comment it out as eventually you will probably want it again.

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly - I'll go an read up on why its useful now :)